# Windows 10 pip not installing Python2 packages while Python 3.6 is installed

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, python

I have Python 3.6 installed but need Python 2.7 for a project. I cannot install packages for Python 2.7 though. Let's use [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) as an example:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

will tell me that requirement is already met in 3.6.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.7.exe install numpy
```

will tell me that requirement is already met in 3.6.

When I try to `import numpy` it will give me an error.

I tried adding Python 2.7 to my path above Python 3.6 and I still get the error.

Please help, this has been extraordinarily frustrating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, running `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install numpy` and `python -m install numpy` (for Python 3.6, outside `C:\Python27\`) yielded no errors for me.

**Troubleshooting**

You may wish to consider one or more of the following.

*Uninstall `numpy`*

Uninstall `numpy` (or any requirements that are already met, assuming you do not need them) in Python 3.6 (ex. `python -m pip uninstall numpy`) and then install e.g. `numpy` again in Python 2.7.

*Use A Virtual Environment*

Assuming that your Python 2.7 installation will allow it:

- Run e.g. `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install virtualenv` to download the `virtualenv` virtual environment package.
- Run `C:\Python27\python.exe -m virtualenv C:\path\to\virtual\env` to create an isolated 2.7 environment in which you can install `numpy` (or any other necessary packages) for your project.
- Note that you will need to "activate" (and perhaps "deactivate") this environment from the command line with the `activate.bat` (or `deactivate.bat)` batch file(s) located in e.g. `C:\path\to\virtual\env\Scripts`.

*Check `pip` Paths*

Running e.g. `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip list` and ex. `python -m pip list` (again, outside `C:\Python27\`) should output different lists of installed packages (one for 2.7 and one for 3.6, respectively).

If they do not, you may wish look for any duplicate references to e.g. `C:\PythonVersion\Scripts` (where  `pip.exe` resides) in your PATH\Path (User\System) variables and remove them. In short, you should only have a single reference to e.g. `C:\Python36\Scripts` (i.e. no `C:\Python27\Scripts`).

*Reinstall Python 2.7 and Python 3.6*

- Completely uninstall Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, taking note of any packages you may wish to reinstall later.
- Install Python 2.7. Do not choose any option to add Python 2.7 to your path variable(s).
- Install Python 3.6. Add it to your path variable(s). You do not need to select the option to add `pip` to your path variables if you are using e.g. `python -m pip` (this is only necessary if you want to use the `pip` installation for Python 3.6 directly as `pip [options]` from the command line)

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I ended up uninstalling all python versions, made sure to delete all files that I could find in my system (for example, completely deleted C:\Python27) and did a fresh install of everything installing packages when import errors arose, also leveraging virtualenvs as you suggested

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad it was helpful.